# Ingress with and without host

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

It is really getting hard to understand and debug the rules for ingress. Can anyone share a good reference?

The question is how the ingress works without specifying the host?

```
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      annotations:
         nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: \"false\"
      name: my-app
    spec:
      rules:
        http:
          paths:
          - backend:
            path: /
              serviceName: my-app
              servicePort: http
```

Upon assigning a host (e.g.`- host: aws-dsn-name.org`) it doesn't  work.
Upon changing the path to `path: /v1/` it also doesn't work :( .

How can I debug/check whether the mapping is correctly done?

Additionally, when to use `extensions/v1beta1` or `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`

Comment: `extensions/v1beta1` is deprecated and won't be available in v1.18. So, you should use `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`.

Comment: I just check now, the version I am running is v1.18.6 (client) and v1.18.3 (server), it seems `extensions/v1beta1` is working

Answer (score 11):

There is pretty good documentation available [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) for getting started. It may not cover all aspects but it does answer your questions. Ingress controller is basically a reverse proxy and follows similar ideas.

1. The snippet you have shared is called single backend or [single service ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#single-service-ingress). `/` Path would be default. It's the only entry so every request on the exposed port will be served by the tied service.
2. Host entry; `host: aws-dns-name.org` should work as long as your DNS is resolving `aws-dns-name.org` to the IP of a node in the cluster or the LB fronting the cluster. Do a ping to that DNS entry and see if it's resolving to the target IP correctly. Try `curl -H 'Host: aws-dns-name.org' IP_Address` to verify if ingress responding correctly. NGINX is using [Host](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-backend) header to decide which backend service to use. If you are sending traffic to IP with a different `Host` entry, it will not connect to the right service and will serve [default-backend](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-backend).
3. If you are doing [path based routing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout), which can be combined with host based routing as well, NGINX will route to the correct backend service based on the intercepted path. However, just like any other reverse proxy, it will send the request to the specified path (http://service:80/v1/). Your application may not be listening on `/v1/` path so you will end up with a 404. Use the `rewrite-target` annotation to let NGINX know that you serving at `/`.
4. API resources versions do switch around in K8s and can be hard to keep up with. The correct annotation now is `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` (`networking.k8s.io/v1` starting 1.19) even though the old version is working but eventually will stop working. I have seen cluster upgrades break applications because somebody forgot to update the API version.

Comment: Thanks Faheen, i just get to know we are using minikube, how ingress work on it? Is it link the minikube is searching for my host (which is my linux machine-ip) and could not find it, which might be the reason for the 2nd question

Comment: Also if i am not specifying the host, does it mean minikube ip will be take by default, if yes then when i hit using my host ip of linux why it works ?- 1st question.

Comment: Actually, Ingress would work the same where ever it is. Your networking stack would change things. Minikube is probably creating an internal network on your machine. You can find out your minikube IP by running `minikube ip`. See if it's the same as your host - just as any VM would do. When you export a service on NodePort, it would try to publish it across all interfaces and give you access to localhost:nodeport.